In ImageMagick, how to create a PDF file from an image with the best Flate compression ratio?
Assume you have a PNM or PNG image file, gray or color. With ImageMagick, you wish to generate a possibly small PDF file from it without losing information.  So far I though it is simply
convert infile.pnm -quality 100 -compress Zip outfile.pdf

or
convert infile.png -quality 100 -compress Zip outfile.pdf

Is that it? After testing, I'm no longer sure that the compression is lossless.

it is. -compress Zip enforces the usage of the DEFLATE compressor. (Calling it Zip is of course completely wrong. Classic ImageMagick API choice…)
Magick uses libdeflate, but for PDF DEFLATE compression, it uses zlib directly (Classic ImageMagick API choice).
It scales the quality parameter of the source image by 1/10, if the source image had a property "compression" of 90, it would become deflateInit(…, 9). (which is very counter-intuitive… the compression is lossfree. The quality is always 100%. The effort is not. And while for lossy formats, the size grows with quality, for Zip it shrinks with quality. Classic ImageMagick API choice…)
However, the original source code line
status=deflateInit(&stream,(int) (image->quality ==
    UndefinedCompressionQuality ? 7 : MagickMin(image->quality/10,9)));

note how the compression setting can never exceed 9 (check, that's Z_BEST_COMPRESSION), so image->quality of 100 is the same as 90; slightly surprising (classic ImageMagick API choice)!
So, unlike cairo, which defaults to zlib's default level (6) ImageMagick convert defaults to compression level 7, unless you specify any quality between 80 and 89, in which case it uses level 8, and starting from 90 it uses level 9.
If you look at https://github.com/inikep/lzbench/blob/master/lzbench18_sorted.md and look for the zlib 1.2.11 -9 and the zlib 1.2.11 -6 lines, you'll notice:



compressor
compression speed
compressed/original size




zlib 1.2.11 -9
14 MB/s
31.92%


zlib 1.2.11 -6 (== Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION)
35 MB/s
32.19%



So, for the test corpus (the Silesia corpus, not only, but also a lot of image data), you increase your computation time by a factor of 2.5 to get 0.27% better compression.
Um. I think the default setting that cairo uses is kind of reasonable!
